# Firefox adding page breaks before large div block when printing

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, firefox, printing

I have a bit of logic in one of my Rails views that states if the `table` I'm about to print is over 7 rows, create a `div` around the `table` with a `min-height` style to make sure the footer below this `table` goes to the end of the page 2, rather than page 1.

I've tested this logic in many browsers including: Chrome, Safari and IE (!) and they all work as expected. Firefox, however, is adding a pesky page-break right before the `div` and `table`. I have tried avoiding this page-break by adding this CSS style in the `div` and also in the `table`: `page-break-before: avoid;` as well as this newer Firefox style: `break-before: avoid;`, but it doesn't seem to affect this page-break during printing. Any other ideas? Does Firefox automagically add a page-break before large divs when printing?

```
<div style='min-height: 1150px;'>
    <table>
     blah blah table stuff...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: According to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before#Browser_compatibility), `break-before` doesn't exist yet. Until it does, use `page-break-before`.

Comment: thanks, but tried page-break-before: avoid; in both the div and in the table tags. didn't work. any other suggestions?

Comment: At this point I changed the min-height selector to height and it works as it should when printing from all browsers. No exactly the solution I wanted, but it gets the job done for now. Would love an actual fix for the min-height in Firefox if anyone has a solution.

Comment: Can you attach/link an example of the full html document that the exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Well, Because we don't have live example of your code Unfortunately is very hard to finger out the solution but the good news is I can provide some information about it might works but not sure.

1. Always insert a page break before each element (when printing).
2. You can't use this property for (an empty **div**) or with (**position:absolute;**).
3. Before using **page-break-before**, check if you can use **break-before** instead.
4. Avoid page break before the element (**if possible**) so is not guaranteed to work, That is why we ask you to provide some live example to work with it.
5. Try to use **page-break-before: inherit;** in the second page to till the second page you are part of the first part of the page.(so if you have one table tray to know where is the last part of the first page and add either **page-break-before: avoid;** , **break-before: avoid;** , **break-before: inherit;** or **page-break-before: inherit;**).
6. If not try to use either (**column-break-before: avoid;** or **-moz-column-break-before: avoid;**) before the beginning of the second page or (**column-break-inside: avoid;** or **-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;**).
7. If not try to use **page-break-inside** or **break-inside** it might the brake is inside not outside.

I hope this will help you to fix your problem and let me know which the most it works for you. Also let me know if you have any question.

Comment: If you would like to do best answer too since you didn't thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, and this will resolve your query

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table { page-break-inside:auto; border-collapse: collapse }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>heading</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><td>notes</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 500 more rows -->
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution came from removing the "border-collapse" css property. If you add that to your answer I'll give you the  bounty in 5 hours.

Comment: too late, i gave it to the other guy

Comment: that's not how it works. you can only award a bounty to one person.

Comment: fyi, you did the opposite of what I asked. `border-collapse` was the property that was causing the problem.'